# Learning Javascipt/Jquery - mysql array in script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to learn javascript/jquery.

I have 2 arrays that hold data:

- The data in $array1[] is `[name1,name2,name3,name4]`
- The data in $array2[] is `[position,position,position,position]`

I know I have to use json_encode to use the data from the php array.

If the script expects the following format
`data : [name,name,name,name],`  it will work cause it will be fed that way.

Im now running into a problem with a script that expects data differently.
like so :

```
var data = [{name: 'Name1 from array', position: 'Position1 from array'},
{name: 'Name2 from array', position: 'Position2 from array'},
{name: 'Name3 from array', position: 'Position3 from array'},
{name: 'Name4 from array', position: 'Position4 from array'},];
```

Comment: Sounds like you have two problems: (i) convert the PHP array so that it just has the data you need: `[name,name,name,name]`, and (ii) convert php data into json. For the second - there will be a library which encodes php arrays into json google 'php encode into json' - and for the first - i'm sure some type of `mapping` function will be available on arrays, so you can get the data that you actually want.

Comment: @BenKoshy thnx, ill look into it!